# Logging in to developer.paypal.com takes me to my live paypal account

Tags: paypal, sandbox

When I try to log in at developer.paypal.com, I'm presented with the login form for my live account at paypal.com. I presume this shouldn't be happening.

Has anyone else experienced this and have a workaround.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's normal.
You log in with your real account and inside the sandbox you can then create sandbox accounts.

Comment: Thanks jsabina but I can't find any links in my live account for creating sandbox accounts. Could this be because I only have a standard account, not business?

Comment: Now i see - I logged in to my live account and in a separate tab, went to developer.paypal.com. The page loaded already logged in and I was able to see sandbox accounts - many thanks

Comment: yes, sorry for the delay.. I know you can create many accounts inside with different emails also not real email just for testing.. but you login always with your main real paypal one